# Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation - for property BackColor

Tags: vb.net, reflection

I get that error when I am trying to setValue for property BackColor for a textBox
What I have is a formBuilder.
So with my formBuilder Runninng I can create a form adding a TabControl and in the tabControl a groupBox. Inside the GroubBox I have some textBoxes.
For each TextBox I save their properties (with the values) in an xml.
When I am trying to recreate the form from the xml (in another project)I use that code:

```
   For Each cntProperty As XElement In elem.Elements
     Dim propertyName As String = cntProperty.Name.ToString
     Dim targetProperty As PropertyInfo = parentControl.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName)
     If targetProperty IsNot Nothing Then
       Dim propType As Type = FindType(targetProperty.PropertyType.ToString)
       Dim convertedVal = ConvertValue(cntProperty.Value, targetProperty.PropertyType)
       parentControl.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(parentControl, convertedVal, Nothing)'Here I get the exception
     End If
    Next
```

parentControl is the control that I am trying to recreate (textBox in this case)
FindType is a function that returns the Type of the property(works fine)
ConvertValue is a function that converts the string from xml to the appropriate type
  For the color I use this function:

```
   Color.FromName(val)'val is the string value from the xml
```

So for some textboxes I have as string value: Color [White]
and after the conversion I have a color: "{Name=Color [White], ARGB=(0, 0, 0, 0)}"
and when I am trying to set this color value to property BackColor I get the exception:
*Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.*
and innerException:
*Control does not support transparent background colors*

Any ideas solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
The problem in my code was actually that the function :

```
 Color.FromName(val as String)
```

doesn't work as expected.I should have as val only the name  (for example white) , but I had "Color [White]"

So I just clean my string before using that function end everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

aRGB(255, 255, 255, 255) is white, the first being the alpha channel - 0 being transparent. The inner exception is correct with winforms controls. WPF does not have this problem.